# Regular expression of the set of strings of even length

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

I should try to write a regular expression of the set of strings of even length over $\{k,l,m\}$ that contain exactly one $k$. If string has even length, and if we have one $k$; there should be (odd length $l$ and even length $m$) or (even length $m$ and odd length $l$). However, I couldn't show them, especially place of $k$ in the expression.

I hope I could tell my ideas correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what rules are available for your definition of regular expression, but following works in Unix (as an extended regular expression): `([lm][lm])*(k[lm]|[lm]k)([lm][lm])*`

**Edit:** (I also removed the unnecessary anchors that Milo Brandt comments on.)

Breaking this down:

- `[lm]` = represents a single character that could be either `l` or `m`. In the wikipedia regex page, this would be expressed by `(l|m)`.
- `( ) * |` all mean the same as explained in the [Basic Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) section of the Wikipedia Regular Expressions page.
- `([lm][lm])*` is thus a string of any even number of `l`s and `m`s.
- `(k[lm]|[lm]k)` is either `k` followed by an `l` or an `m`, or it is an `l` or `m` followed by a `k`.

So the whole expressions says "a string starting with any number of any of the substrings `ll, lm, ml, mm`, followed by one of the substrings `kl, km, lk, lm`, followed by any number of any of the substrings `ll, lm, ml, mm`.

Every string from $\{m, l, k\}$ of even length with exactly one $k$ in it will match this.

Comment: The `^` and `$` are certainly not necessary here; it's generally implied that the regex should match the whole string, not just a substring.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I didn't understand that. I should define a language with given rule like $m^{*} \cup kl^{+}$

Comment: @fillhora - unfortunately, I don't understand that. All I can say is my language is well-documented (look up the manual page for "egrep"). As Milo points out, the "^" and "$" anchors are not needed in a formal setting. To translate it into wikipedias "basic concepts", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts , replace "[lm]" everywhere with "(l|m)", so it becomes `((l|m)(l|m))*(k(l|m)|(l|m}k)((l|m)(l|m))*`.

Comment: @fillhora - I see a comment on the Wikipedia Regex page that some sources use $\cup$ instead of `|` for alternation. So perhaps you also need to replace all of my `|` with $\cup$ to translate into your language.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you sir, I can understand now